# C# - Don't bring form to front

Tags: c#, forms

My apps use a timer that display a form after some seconds.
When I minimize my apps to do other stuff, the timer is still active (I'm ok with that) and the form bring to front over all my windows with focus on it (normal behavior).

I want that the new form open above my main apps but not above all my windows.

In the main form, I call the new form like this :

```
MRIS.EVENT_BOX form1 = new MRIS.EVENT_BOX();
form1.Owner = this;
form1.ShowDialog();
```

I manage to remove the focus problem by adding this in the EVENT_BOX :

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation { get { return true; } }
```

I also check that TopMost is set to false in the new form.

But the new form is still show above all the others (without focus this time...).

I check some other questions but cannot manage to find something useful.

Some people talk about visible form ?

If you can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Showing as dialog (`ShowDialog`) means that the form will be shown 'on top' of the original form -- in particular, the new form must be closed before the original form can be used again. It is meant to be used for *dialogs*. If you simply want to show another form, then `Show` is the method you want, as indicated by @Leopard.

Comment: Not entirely clear from your question what you want to happen when the timer ticks.. is "main apps" other unrelated apps that are open and "all my windows" the rest of the windows in your c# app? When the timer ticks which window do you want to have on top?

Comment: @Steve16351: "all my windows" refer to all the windows not related to my apps. I want to launch my app, switch to anything else, for example browsing internet and let my apps display a form without showing it on top of all windows. Then, when finishing browsing internet, I switch back to my app and see my form above my main app form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `form1.Show();` if you don't want to bring it to front

```
form1.Show();
//form1.BringToFront() You may need to call this if you want to being it to front
```

`form1.ShowDialog()` shows the form as `dialog` which means it will be shown on top of `parent form`. You can check more details on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Hi Leopard, thanks for your answer, my form still show at top of all my windows (not related to my apps) but this time only the form is display without executing the code related to it (as explain in the link you provide). So it did solve the "problem'.

Comment: sorry for my last sentence "So it did solve the "problem".", The problem isn't solved.